# Is Disguise Self enough to transform a character into a Death Knight

Tags: dnd-5e

The way I read Disguise Self, it would work. My biggest hang up is turning your physical form into a skeleton and making your eyes glow.

Would it make more sense to use Alter Self for that part of the disguise, then Disguise Self for the armor and equipment?

Answer (score 11):

Let's look at the text.

> You make yourself look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. **Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.**

Seems pretty clear that you can *look* however you want. However the rules also state:

> If someone attempts to touch you, they will be able to pass through the illusion and learn that you are disguised. Otherwise, to discern that you are disguised, a creature can use its action to make an Intelligence (Investigation) check against your spell save DC.

So disguise self is easier to 'figure out'. Alter self actually changes your form, but also requires Concentration.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, Disguise Self is enough to appear like a Death Knight.

> **Disguise Self**
> You make yourself look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can *appear thin, fat, or in between*. You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. *Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you*.

I don't think that you can appear like skeleton, because it would not qualify as appearing thin, fat, or in between.
However, Death Knights wear plate armor, which covers the entire body so you don't have to appear like a skeleton, you just need to appear like you're wearing plate armor with glowing eyes.
Disguise Self places no constraints on those two things, so you can do them.